# adding text in between a string in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a string that looks like this in one cell:

> Col1Col2Col3Col4Col5

it goes all the way to Col100.

I want to use one formula without VBA and add a comma in between the Col to make the text look like this:

> Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5

again all the way to Col100.

I'm thinking some kind of find replace function in excel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a formula:

```
=LEFT(A1,1)&SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,2,1024),"Col",",Col")
```

1024 is an assumed maximum number of characters in a cell.

If not every cell contains this text then you could only substitute if the cell begins with "Col":

```
=IF(LEFT(A1,3)="Col",LEFT(A1,1)&SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,2,255),"Col",",Col"),A1)
```

Comment: sweet. thanks. quick question, what is the "255" for in the mid function? is that arbitrary?

Comment: Yes, I just made it up. But if your cells go up to Col100 then use 1000.

Comment: Another way would be to replace every Col with ,Col and then eliminate the first comma - =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"Col",",Col"),",","",1)